# How to show form access 2010 with visual basic

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've created a database with access 2010 and after that I created a form called User from the table User:
[image]

and here how I can run this form to get showed in my screen like it have been showed in Access. However, when I press on visual basic button it show me this :

[image]

so in this later interface I want to run my application and show me the form user.
if I clicked on execute it tell me choose a macro :(.

thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question are you looking for `DoCmd.OpenForm "Form_User"`?

Comment: I don't know I m biggener but if I click on exécute from the second intaerface or hit on "F5" then I want turn my application the form "from_User" will be showed @Linger. thanks.

Comment: You just need to double-click on the name of your form in the Access main window. In the Navigation pane, you'll find "Forms", and under there is your "User" form.

Comment: it's not I want, I want just How To Open Form Access  Without or Outside Access in Full Screen Mode. @MP24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of Objects in the Access Object List is there for you to double-click and open/view/run queries, tables, forms, reports, modules, etc.

The reason you see nothing in your VBA code editor is because there is no code that was written. This is not like F5 (Debug mode) in Visual Studio.

You must create a Module that will be handled when something occurs to do something else (it could be to open your form). This is what your question is hinting at.

Even if you wrote code in the VBA behind the form, let's say, to handle a button click - You still wouldn't be able to click F5 and run your program in debug mode to test that code. You would have to actually click that button to trigger that code.

As far as opening forms, MS Access wasn't created to be just like Visual Studio. It was made to have a fairly simple interface that wouldn't necessary rely on a lot of coding, but it had the option. So when you click F5, it's not going to look for an entire program to run.

[Open a form at startup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/set-the-default-form-that-appears-when-you-open-a-database-or-web-application-HA010341995.aspx)

[Opening a form via VBA](http://codevba.com/msaccess/docmd_openform.htm)

Comment: ok thanks I will try you did understand and thanks for all :)